# Eigenproblem to solve 1D wave equation in matlab

Tags: matlab, numerical-methods, derivative

I've constructed the following code to solve the 1D wave equation  as a function of radius r from 0 to pi. This equation is shown in the graphic below:

[image]

I have taken the constant in front of the spatial derivative c is equal to 1 but I have coded this in general since I wish to eventually make this a variable dependent on r. By assuming plane wave solutions, the solution can be reduced to the following:

[image]

I have now used finite difference and discretise the 2nd order DE on the right hand side into a matrix A in an attempt to reduce the problem to solving for eigenvalues and eigenvectors,i.e:

The code I have produced is shown below:

```
%eigensolver code

clear
clc

%NOTE: place % in front of Neumann code when solving using Dirchlet
%condition and vise versa so that the code only inputs one type of boundary
%condition

%Specify initial variables
ri=0;               %inital radius             
rf=pi;               %final radius
Di=0;               %initial Direchlet point
Df=0;               %final Direchlet point
Ni=0;               %initial Neumann point
Nf=0;               %final Neumann point




Nr=5;
h=abs(rf-ri)/(Nr-1);  %step size
r=ri:h:rf;
A=zeros(Nr,Nr);
b=ones(size(r));
c=b;
%code inital/final point assuming Dirichlet condition
%initial
A(1,1)=-(2*(c(1)^2))/(h^2);
A(1,2)=(c(1)^2)/(h^2);
%final
A(Nr,Nr)=-(2*(c(Nr)^2))/(h^2);
A(Nr,Nr-1)=(c(Nr)^2)/(h^2);

%code initial and final points assuming Neumann condition
%initial
%A(1,1)=-(3.*(c(1)^2))./(2*h);
%A(1,2)=(2.*(c(1)^2))./h;
%A(1,3)=-(c(1)^2)/(2*h);
%final
%A(Nr,Nr-2)=(c(end)^2)/(2*h);
%A(Nr,Nr-1)=-(2*(c(end)^2))/h;
%A(Nr,Nr)=(3*(c(end)^2))/(2*h);

%interior points
for k=2:Nr-1
    A(k,k-1)=(c(k)^2)/(h^2);
    A(k,k)=-(2*(c(k)^2))/(h^2);
    A(k,k+1)=(c(k)^2)/(h^2);
end

[evec, eigval]=eig(A)
```

My question is made up of a few parts:

1) How do I know if I have found the correct answer to the numerical problem? Is there some  prespecified function in matlab i can call? I am not very versed in eigenproblems so I don't know how to interpret my answer.

2) If u look in the code above, I can change Dirichlet boundary conditions for Neumann boundary conditions. Is this part of the code the correct way to implement these conditions for this 1D case?

Comment: Dirichlet*. Also dont use "eval" s a variable name, as it is a Matlab built-in function and you are overwriting it.

Comment: The question has been amended for the changes you suggested @ander-biguri

Answer (score 0):

You can think of an eigenproblem with PDE as follows.

If A is a finite dimensional matrix, v one of its eigenvectors and l the corresponding eigenvalue, then:

Av = lv

Now instead of a finite dimensional matrix A you can take your (infinite dimensional) differential operator of the PDE. In this case your eigenvector is now an eigenfunction as D works on a space of functions (Hope this helps to understand this).

Regarding your code: You should not include your boundary conditions in the stiffness matrix. You want to solve the discretized problem

Ax=b,

where A is your stiffness matrix, x are your grid points and b are the values at your grid points. Therefore you should implement your boundary conditions inside b.

If you want further reading, explanations:

The following link is for the numerical PDE 1 course at TUM
[Numerical methods for PDE](https://www-m3.ma.tum.de/NumPDE1516/WebHome).
Here you will find some explanations about [finite differences method](https://www-m3.ma.tum.de/junge/NumPDE15/MA3303_Ch2.pdf).
The course webpage will provide you with lecture notes, code examples, etc.